# How to generate file.txt if pop-up click on sg.Submit() from PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, if-statement, user-controls

I'm trying to put this line of code inside this gui ...

---

```
try:
    name_file = input('Name:')
    file= open(name_file, 'r+')
except FileNotFoundError:
    file= open(name_file, 'w+')
    file.writelines(u'file!')
file.close()
```

---

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Name1', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name2', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name3', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],

    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout, background_color="white")
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()
# print(event, values[0])

try:
    name_file = input('Name:')
    file= open(name_file, 'r+')
except FileNotFoundError:
    file= open(name_file, 'w+')
    file.writelines(u'file!')
file.close()
```

- python 3.7 ( import PySimpleGUI as sg )

Comment: Why don't you use `values[0]` as `name_file` or text in file ? You don't have to put this code to GUI. You can use it after it close window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put it in GUI. You can use it after GUI.

You can use event to check what button was pressed and then you can ask for filename and write data in file.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Name1', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name2', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name3', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],

    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout, background_color="white")
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()

if event == 'Submit':
    try:
        name_file = input('Name:')
        file= open(name_file, 'r+')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        file= open(name_file, 'w+')

    all_values = values.values() # values from dictionary
    text = "\n".join(all_values) # put values in separated lines
    file.write(text)             # write all as one string

    file.close()
```

You could create GUI to ask for filename.

---

**EDIT:** I used GUI to ask for filename.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Name1', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name2', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Name3', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],

    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout, background_color="white")
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()

if event == 'Submit':
    # create before next GUI because I want to use the same name for variable `values`
    all_values = values.values() # values from dictionary
    text = "\n".join(all_values) # put values in separated lines

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Filename', size=(15, 1), background_color="white" ), sg.InputText()],

        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Test', layout, background_color="white")
    event, values = window.Read()
    window.Close()

    if event == 'Submit':
        name_file = values[0]

        try:
            fh = open(name_file, 'r+')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            fh = open(name_file, 'w+')

        fh.write(text) # write all as one string

        fh.close()
```

Comment: I added version with second GUI window for filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the high-level `Popup` functions to get your filename which will remove the requirement to open your own window and compacts the code down to this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

name_file = sg.PopupGetText('Enter Filename')
if name_file:
    try:
        file = open(name_file, 'r+')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        file = open(name_file, 'w+')
        file.writelines(u'file!')
```

There is also a `Popup` that enables you to browse for a filename called PopupGetFile.  The advantage is has over the `PopupGetText` is that you get the same ability to paste in the filename into the input box, but you also get a "Save As..." button to browse for the file if you prefer that way.  Using it, your code would be:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

name_file = sg.PopupGetFile('Enter Filename', save_as=True)
if name_file:
    try:
        file = open(name_file, 'r+')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        file = open(name_file, 'w+')
        file.writelines(u'file!')
```